# AWS S3 Public Object vs Private Object?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Back in S3, I have URL's to images in my bucket that I will be presenting in my application, however they are set private. When I try to click on the link, it reads "access denied". When I change the setting of the link to public, It goes through, however I've read that public access isn't the safest thing. So this is essentially a two part question,

1) What is the difference between a public and private link/Object in a bucket?

2)And how can i make a private link/object in my bucket accessible to both myself and my users?

Answer (score 6):

Private objects require authentication; public objects do not.

With regard to your comment "public access isn't the safest thing", you typically need to consider a couple of things when deciding whether or not to make an S3 object public:

1. [major] is it OK for *anyone* to download it? If the content of the object is something that you should not be sharing with the world, for example a user's family photos, then the answer is "no".
2. [minor] do you want to pay every time some unknown person downloads an object. As the bucket owner, you pay for data transfer out (unless you opt for 'requester pays' in which case the requester needs to authenticate).

There are at least two ways that you can make **private** S3 objects available to your users without them being accessible to the entire world:

1. use time-limited, pre-signed URLs for the objects (see [this article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html))
2. proxy the object downloads yourself so that all requests for objects go to your app server and can therefore be restricted to authenticated sessions.

Comment: well to give a better explanation of my situation, my application has users sign up through parse, but the images are hosted from s3. Once they sign up, they can view the images freely. so would public links be the best thing or?

Comment: If an image is public then anyone with the URL can download the image, bypassing your system. Any of your users would be able to share the image URLs with 1000s of people via a blog post, for example. I don't know if that would be a problem for you or not.

Comment: my thing is how would they bypass my system if the url is an image that loads into a collection view cell? strictly just a UIImageView.

Comment: To get an object directly from S3, your app has to make an HTTP request. That request can be logged or intercepted in many places. Ideally your image loader would be using HTTPS but that's beside the point. The point is that if the images that you are retrieving are not public, for example if your users have an expectation that these images will not be made public, then you need to make them private. It might help if you gave more information about the objects you are serving from S3.

Comment: the objects I'm serving from s3 are thumbnail images to articles, magazines etc.

Comment: i mean i would love to make them private, but still give my users access to them, but the thing is i don't use AWS as a user authenticator, i use parse as my BaaS.. s3 is just the storage

Comment: It doesn't sound like the thumbnails would need to be private but that's your call, of course. BTW you can still supply pre-signed URLs to your users even though they are not AWS users - your app server authenticates to AWS, creates the pre-signed URLs, and then transmits the URLs to the client app (in a web page or via REST or whatever).

Comment: oh okay, but i will be providing PDF's so i definitely need those private.

Comment: so is that what you suggest i do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88519/discussion-between-jarmod-and-john-durand).

Comment: check the chat , i replied

Comment: Hi, where can I find a sample for this? i.e uploading and downloading the image to S3 with private access in ios? or if you guys have a sample please provide.