# Is it neccesary to make audio files public in S3 in order to play on alexa devices

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am making an alexa skill where user can listen to audio which I have uploaded in S3 but these doesn't play untill I make them public, is there any way to fix it? Why is it required to make the files public, isn't it risky?

There is one way they have suggested in javascript, they provide an api in their Utils package a function with name "getS3PreSignedURL" which will make object public for 60 seconds but what if my audio plays more than 60 seconds and I am working on Java, I am not so confident on javascript.
Have anyone faced similar issue, any thoughts will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can use an S3 presigned url. The one used in [Alexa Hosted Skills](https://alexa.design/hosted) imposes a limit of 60 seconds but that's enforced on the S3 side. You can configure your own S3 bucket to support this and set your custom timeout. If you check the file `util.js` in an Alexa Hosted skill you'll see something like this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const s3SigV4Client = new AWS.S3({
    signatureVersion: 'v4'
});

module.exports = {
    getS3PreSignedUrl(s3ObjectKey) {
        const bucketName = process.env.S3_PERSISTENCE_BUCKET;
        const s3PreSignedUrl = s3SigV4Client.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: s3ObjectKey,
            Expires: 60*1 // the Expires is capped for 1 minute
        });
        console.log(`Util.s3PreSignedUrl: ${s3ObjectKey} URL ${s3PreSignedUrl}`);
        return s3PreSignedUrl;
    }
}
```

Notice that this code is using the standard AWS SDK for node.js. The S3 bucket is taken from the environment `process.env.S3_PERSISTENCE_BUCKET` and is the one that imposes the 60 sec timeout. If you change the `Expires` property to more than 60 secs you'll basically fail to retrieve the pre signed url if you try after 1 minute. But, if you pass your own bucket there (and assign it to `bucketName`) which is properly configured to support pre signed urls and timeouts greater than 60 secs, then nothing prevents you from reusing this code (or equivalent code in Java) and get a pre signed url with any expiration you want. The parameter `s3ObjectKey` is the relative path of the file in the bucket. To do this in Java you'll have to use [this SDK instead](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/).

Answer (score 1):

See [AWS S3 Public Object vs Private Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339333/aws-s3-public-object-vs-private-object)

I think that answers your concerns on risk, and some other options.

You might also be able to find a parameter to make that function return a longer window - as an aside, it looks like it's still authenticating your user to use that link, as opposed to making it truly public (available to anyone without authentication).